# How to continuously input some strings and then print them and the number of strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, input

I am learning Java. I have a `Scanner` and I know how to input one `String`. How to continuously input some `String`s and then print them and the number of `String`s in Java?

My code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
//Get input String
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
str = in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Input String is: "+str);
```

The result I want:

```
Enter a string: Item1
Input String: Item1, Number of items: 1
```

Comment: how are you even getting that output ?

Comment: You have to correctly define your variables, try `String str = in.nextLine();` Besides, your expected output doesn't match the code you've provided.

Comment: You know about `nextLine`. You know about variables. You know about `System.out.println`. What are you asking for?

Comment: Ah so you **want** to track the amount of items added. Then you could look into using [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `while` loop to input as many `String` as you want. You can also record the number of items you inputted in the `while` loop.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int numberOfItem = 0;
String str;

while(true) {
    //Get input String
    System.out.print("Enter a string(enter QUIT to quit): ");
    str = in.nextLine();

    if (str.equals("QUIT")) break;
    numberOfItem++;

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Input String is: " + str);
    System.out.println(", Number of items: " + numberOfItem);
}
```

Comment: Don't repost your deleted answer just because you don't like the downvotes you received.

Comment: I did what the user want, tell me why you downvote me.

Comment: This is what I want. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Type `EXIT` to finish and show results:

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = "", tmp;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a string: (Type EXIT to exit");
    while(true){
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        tmp = in.nextLine();
        if(tmp.equals("EXIT"))
            break;
        count++;
        str += tmp + ", ";
    }
    System.out.println("Input String: " + str + "Number of items: " + count);
```